# Solr: Query Facet and count missing

Tags: solr, facet

In my Solr index I have an optional date field. Let's call it `Property_3_1044`.

I want to **find the maximum** and the **minimum** of `Property_3_1044` as well as the number of all **items without that date**.

I believe faceting is the best approach. Please correct me if there is a better way!

---

**Using [Query Facets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/json-facet-api.html#query-facet) I can use aggregate functions `min` and `max` to obtain minimum and maximum, respectively**:

[http://localhost:8983/solr/Shard/query?q=*:*&json.facet={Date1:{type:query,facet:{"min":"min(Property_3_1044)","max":"max(Property_3_1044)"}}}&rows=0](http://localhost:8983/solr/Shard/query?q=*:*&json.facet=%7BDate1:%7Btype:query,facet:%7B%22min%22:%22min(Property_3_1044)%22,%22max%22:%22max(Property_3_1044)%22%7D%7D%7D&rows=0)

Result:

```
"facets":{
  "count":249,
  "Date1":{
    "count":249,
    "min":"2019-01-09T00:00:00Z",
    "max":"2019-01-22T00:00:00Z"}}}
```

(Question aside: How to get rid of the 2 `count`s?)

---

**Using [Terms Facets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/json-facet-api.html#terms-facet) I can use the `missing` parameter to find all items without date**:

[http://localhost:8983/solr/Shard/query?q=*:*&rows=0&json.facet={Date2:{terms:{field:Property_3_1044,missing:true,limit:0}}}](http://localhost:8983/solr/Shard/query?q=*:*&rows=0&json.facet=%7BDate2:%7Bterms:%7Bfield:Property_3_1044,missing:true,limit:0%7D%7D%7D)

Result:

```
"facets":{
  "count":249,
  "Date2":{
    "buckets":[],
    "missing":{
      "count":240}}}}
```

---

How can I *combine* these two queries? I know I can just execute both (by just concatenating the two queries strings), but I'd like to know whether there is a more efficient way. I assume that performing both a query facet and a terms facet is more expensive than just having a single facet. For example, an aggregate function `missing` would allow me to do everything just using the query facet (but there is no such method, is there?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself; I just need to add a facet query `q` which filters for not-null values -> `[* TO *]`:

[http://localhost:8983/solr/Shard/query?q=*:*&json.facet={Date1:{type:query,q:"Property_3_1044:[* TO *]",facet:{"min":"min(Property_3_1044)","max":"max(Property_3_1044)"}}}&rows=0](http://localhost:8983/solr/Shard/query?q=*:*&json.facet=%7BDate1:%7Btype:query,q:%22Property_3_1044:[*%20TO%20*]%22,facet:%7B%22min%22:%22min(Property_3_1044)%22,%22max%22:%22max(Property_3_1044)%22%7D%7D%7D&rows=0)

In the result, the outer count is the number of all items (here: 225) and the inner facet count will give the the number of items with date set, ie. after `q` was applied (here: 9):

```
"facets":{
  "count":225,
  "Date1":{
    "count":9,
    "min":"2019-01-09T00:00:00Z",
    "max":"2019-01-22T00:00:00Z"}}}
```

The number of items *without* date is the difference (225-9=216).