# Solr faceting based on function result

Tags: solr

I'm trying to perform faceting based on a dynamic value. Basically I want identical behavior to the `def` function, but that doesn't seem to be available with faceting.

Consider these two "products":

```
{
  "id":"product1",
  "defaultPrice":19.99,
  "overridePrice":14.99
},
{
  "id":"product2",
  "defaultPrice":49.99
}
```

I want to add that `overridePrice` is just an example. The actual field is a dynamic value that will depend on what context a search is performed in, and there may be many overridden prices, so I can't just derive `price` at index time.

For the response, I'm doing something like this for `fl`:

`fl=price:def(overridePrice, defaultPrice)` and using the same `def` function to perform sorting on `price`. This works fine.

So now I want to apply the same logic to facets. I've tried using `json.facet`, which seemed like it would work:

```
json.facet={
  price: "def(overridePrice, defaultPrice)"
}
```

I've tried other variations as well, such as using `field:def(overridePrice, defaultPrice)` as well as `field:price`, but `def` doesn't seem to be an available function for faceting, and the `price` derived field is not available when faceting.

So the question: How can I perform faceting based on a default field like I'm doing for `fl` and sorting? Will this require a custom aggregation function, or is there a clever way I can do this without a custom function? It would be much more preferable to be able to do this with built-in Solr functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a hacky solution based on a tip in [another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347580/solr-query-facet-and-count-missing/54365051#54365051)

We can use two facets with a query to filter documents depending on if a field exists.

Example:

```
{
  price_override: {
    type: query,
    q: "overridePrice:[* TO *]",
    facet: {
      price_override:{
        type:terms,
        field: overridePrice
      }
    }
  },
  price_standard: {
    type: query,
    q: "-overridePrice:[* TO *] AND defaultPrice:[* TO *]",
    facet: {
        price_standard: {
        type: terms,
        field: defaultPrice
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation:

```
price_override: {
        type: query,
        q: "overridePrice:[* TO *]"
```

This range query only selects documents that have an `overridePrice` field.

```
price_standard: {
        type: query,
        q: "-overridePrice:[* TO *] AND defaultPrice:[* TO *]"
```

`-overridePrice:[* TO *]` omits documents with the `overridePrice` field, and selects documents with a `defaultPrice` field.

And the facet response:

```
"facets":{
    "count":2,
    "price_override":{
      "count":1,
      "price_override":{
        "buckets":[{
            "val":14.99,
            "count":1}]}},
    "price_standard":{
      "count":1,
      "price_standard":{
        "buckets":[{
            "val":49.99,
            "count":1}]}}}
```

This does require manually grouping `price_override` and `price_standard` into a single facet group, but the results are as expected. This could also pretty easily be tweaked into a ranged query, which is my use case.

Comment: Want to add that there's a better way of doing this, and that's with delimited payload fields. These allow storing many values in a single field, and is a very good solution for this type of problem. https://lucidworks.com/post/solr-payloads/